# cURL login remote and browse through the site and download

Tags: php, curl, browser-cache

I have a curl script that is used to remote control a login a website. The website has some data in its various menu(links). with this script I can log in to the website but I can not download any data. because after logging in whenever I click any link it logged me out and take me to the login page again.

```
<?php
$url='';
$login_email = '*******';
$login_pass = '*******';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '$url');
curl_setopt($ch, 



 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'identity='.urlencode($login_email). 
'&password='.urlencode($l
ogin_pass).'&login=Login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 
5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
echo $page;

?>
```

Comment: typo a quote before $url. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '$url);

Comment: thats not the issue. that was a typo corrected here. i mentioned i can log in with this piece of code. but i can not browse to next pages.

Comment: _“but i can not browse to next pages”_ - show us where you’re doing that then.

Comment: i agree with @CBroe, show us the code where you try to navigate to the next page. but it could be a million reasons for it, which is best debugged by checking how a browser like Chrome navigates, then emulate that with curl.
if you can give us the real url, and a test username & password, we could probably help you more.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is not on curl.

Try to have session_start(); on all the pages.

Comment: i do not have edit permission in those pages. i want to automate some downloading after logging in to that system.